# How to disable submit action

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms

Hi i have have this form that i do no want to perform an action when the submit button is clicked. All i want to do is perform the a function that loads data into a div. Any Ideas??

```
<form  method="POST"   action="" id="search-form">
          <input type="text" name="keywords"  />
          <input type="submit" value="Search" id="sButton" onclick="loadXMLDoc('file.xml')" />
</form>
```

Comment: have you tried ajax using jquery?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
onclick="loadXMLDoc('file.xml'); return false;"
```

or even better:

```
<script>
    window.onload = function() { 
        document.getElementById("search-form").onsubmit = function() { 
            loadXMLDoc('file.xml');
            return false;
        };
    };
</script>
```

To implement loadXMLDoc, you can use the ajax module in jQuery. for example:

```
function loadXMLDoc() { 
    $("div").load("file.xml");
}
```

Final code using jQuery:

```
<script>
    $(function() { 
        $("#search-form").submit(function() { 
            $("div").load("file.xml");
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Is `e.preventDefault()` better or `return false` better in this case?

Comment: `return false` is better because it prevents the default behavior of the event **and also** prevents the page from bubbling up. Note that this is only correct in jQuery event handlers.

Comment: @Alon Gubkin—what do you mean by "…this is only correct in jQuery event handlers"? Using `return false` from a submit listener will cancel submit whether you are using jQuery or not.

Comment: @RobG but it won't cancel the page from bubbling up in non-jQuery event handlers.

Comment: @AlonGubkin—I presume you are talking about the event bubbling. Given that the submit event in most browsers doesn't bubble anyway, that forms can't be nested so the submit of one bubbles to another and that putting a submit listener on any other element doesn't make much sense, precisely what "problem" does stopping it bubbling solve that outweighs having to add 100kb of minified library to do what can be done in two words of code?

Comment: @RobG—I only said to @Derek that in jQuery `return false` automatically prevents event bubbling. I didn't *suggest* including jQuery just to prevent event bubbling when it's possible with `event.stopPropagation`.

Comment: More correct answer would be. return false only works on jquery. 
preventDefault would be the correct answer. If you don't want it to bubble stopPropagation is the way which does no relation to question.

Answer (score 3):

I think you need ajax function to load data with in `div` without page reload

Change input type `submit` to `button`

```
<input type="button" value="Search" id="sButton" onclick="AjaxSend()" />
```

Ajax CAll:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function AjaxSend(){
         $.get('file.xml', function(data) {
              $('div').html(data);
          });
     }
</script>
```

Comment: You mean onclick="javascript:AjaxSend()" ... I wonder if it works everywhere now.  It should, btw.

Answer (score 1):

use prevent defaults to avoid form action.please refer the code below it might help you

```js
function createRecord(){ 
 event.preventDefault();
 
}
```

```html
<form>

<input type="text"/>
<input type="submit" onclick="createRecord()"/>

</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

just remove `action` param from `form` and add `onsubmit="return false"`. It will return false everytime you click on any button in your form.
Try like this:

```
<form  method="POST" onsubmit="return false" id="search-form">
          <input type="text" name="keywords"  />
          <input type="submit" value="Search" id="sButton" onclick="loadXMLDoc('file.xml')" />
</form>
```